# CSS Template Design

Tags: html, css

Something is strange to me. For Example I have seen a CSS2.0 based template that It has a 2000 pixels width as header,but the template won't be scrolled,I have put that image into my css but my template scrolled. Should I

Set Overflow Property ? Or it is something new to me ?

Comment: can we see the template?

Comment: why you rate it down? the question is general , no code is available!

Answer (score 1):

you should put the Overflow property

```
overflow: hidden;
```

or

```
overflow: visible;
```

Comment: What is the best way that a template won't be scrolled ?

Comment: overflow is the best ,but be aware of being overridden from other rules